# Newbie to induction attempt to find natural deduction proof with given axioms

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

I am trying to prove the conjecture:

$∀x.∀y.∀z.(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$

I have access to the following axioms plus induction, and the others regular rules of natural deduction.

$A1: nat(0)$

$A2: nat(T) ⊢ nat(s(T))$

$A3: nat(T), nat(U) ⊢ nat(T+U)$

$A4: nat(T), nat(U) ⊢ nat(T · U)$

$A5: 1=s(0)$

$A6: ∀x. 0+x=x$

$A7: ∀x.∀y.s(x)+y=s(x+y)$

$A8: ∀x.0·x = 0$

$A9: ∀x.∀y.s(x)·y = y + x · y$

I am really close to completing this proof however I am not sure about how to complete it with the brackets issues...:

[image: Induction proof attempt]

Comment: You have omitted a crucial "+" sign in your conjecture ...

Comment: @PeterSmith Sorry

Comment: Please, fix the third line of your text: "I have access to the following axioms, **plus** induction schema, and the others regular rules of natural deduction." :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble you are having is because you never use your inductive hypothesis (line 16).  This is what you need to go through:

$(s(a2) + a3) + a4 = (\text{using} A7: s(a2) + a3 = s(a2 + a3))$

$s(a2 + a3) + a4 = (\text{using } A7 \text{ again})$

$s((a2 + a3) + a4) = (\text{use inductive hypothesis! }(a2 + a3) + a4 = a2 + (a3 + a4))$

$s(a2 + (a3 + a4)) =(\text{using } A7)$

$s(a2) + (a3 + a4)$

Below is a formal proof using the computer program called Fitch (which comes with the book Language Proof and Logic):

[image]

Please note how the formal proof closely mirrors the mathematical algebraic proof as shown at the beginning of this post: for every mathematical step, I do two steps in the formal proof, a $\forall \: Elim$ followed by a $= \: Elim$. I also start with a 'LHS=LHS' (LHS: left-hand side) statement at the start using a $= \: Intro$ to get the gradual transformation started.  I know you do all these steps at some point as well in your proof, but the order in which you do them seem a bit less organized, so I encourage you to follow the systematic transformation as I do in my proof, because otherwise it is very easy to get lost in all the symbol strings, as I am sure you have noticed!

OK, I got the darn thing ... what a hellish interface!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't follow. [Or didn't before "and induction!"]

Take the model for Robinson Arithmetic and hence your arithmetic at p. 69 of my Gödel book -- and you will see that in that model, with $a$ and $b$ as defined, $(a + b) + a \neq a + (b + a)$.

The basic point is that, since you have no induction axiom inside your arithmetic, you can prove almost none of even the simplest general truths of arithmetic.

I'm being a bit terse, as I have already answered a similar question from the OP -- I'm not sure what book/set of lecture notes is being used here, but something is going awry.

Comment: I was able to prove the previous question I posted with the help of another poster...  @Bram28 though? http://imgur.com/KhwnJqI

Comment: No that answer was, I'm afraid, wrong.

Comment: I am allowed to use induction I am not limited to only use the axioms. Maybe I am wording the question wrong...

Comment: What do you mean by induction? Induction as an axiom schema in the arithmetic? Or induction as a principle for reasoning *about* your arithmetic system?

Comment: I have also got access to the following:  Split on Condition, Split on 0, Induction,  ≠-intro (¬x=y ⊢ x≠y),  ≠-elim (x≠y ⊢ ¬x=y), =-intro, =-elim, =-symmetric (x=y ⊢ y=x).

Comment: Which version of induction? (Judging from your proof,  induction inside the arithmetic -- but then you should have listed that as an axiom schema I guess!)

Comment: It can be used as an axiom I did not understand that people were thinking that I meant that you could only use those provided axioms. I thought the above was always available to be used in all proofs...

Comment: I thought you were always allowed to use it sorry... I am really new to logic :( I understand you being a bit "terse" I apologize for that :)

Comment: The crucial thing to distinguish is induction in the informal maths you use to argue *about* a formal theory [you can always use that, and all the rest of the maths you know!!!] and induction axioms *inside* e.g. a formal theory of arithmetic [whether there are such induction axioms differs from theory to theory, and you always need to specify].

Comment: @PeterSmith It seems that the OP has access to induction as an inference rule, where if you are working with the natural numbers, and if you have $\varphi(0)$ and $\forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(s(x))$ then you can infer $\forall x \varphi(x)$. You are of course right that the OP should have let us know the availability of this rule in the first place (given its crucial use for the problem at hand), but as a beginner in logic I can understand why the OP didn't list this as one of the axioms, as the system the OP is working with treats it as an inference rule.

Comment: @PeterSmith Looking at the use of that rule: http://imgur.com/Lji6vTT it *is* curious how they are formalizing induction, since the induction rule only makes reference to lines 1 and 10 ... which by themselves of course do not logically imply line 11 ... but it must be the fact that line 10 itself was obtained using this $nat(a)$ context that made it ok for induction to be applied.

Comment: @Bram28 Yep would help if the OP had, as asked, specified the book she is referring to so we can see what is supposed to be happening! (On a quite different matter, I wonder if you could contact me privately -- I have something you might be interested in  ... my email address is at the foot of the logicmatters about page linked to my network profile here!)